# Outside temp of vessel of is 40 Deg C and Water inside it is 86 Deg C.. Why?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, home-experiment

I was boiling water in a steel utensil.

Used Fluke's IR Gun (59 Max) to measure the temperature of Water inside AND the surface temp of vessel outside.

The boiling water read 86 Deg C whereas the outside surface temp of vessel read just 40 Deg C. Why is that? If I touched the outside of the vessel it would 'feel' extremely hot but measurement shows just 40 Deg C. So what's going on here?

[image: Temp of Boiling Water Inside the Vessel]

[image: Surface Temp of Vessel outside]

Comment: Maybe you could take a black pen and draw a black dot on the vessel. Then you measure (a) on the black dot and (b) at a point close to the black dot and report the two temperatures. I reckon everybody would agree that drawing a black dot on the vessel will not change the temperature.

Comment: Adding a black dot actually reported a temperature much closer to the hot boiling water temp... With black dot, the temp recorded was 73 Deg C..!!

Comment: So, I reckon we agree that @Superfast Jellyfish gave the correct answer. Thus, all what is left is accepting his answer. Thank you Rahul, that was a nice question.

Answer (score 2):

How these thermometers works is based on the principle of blackbody radiation and the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). There is an IR sensor housed inside the thermometer that senses the total power radiated in a window of IR. And this power is related to the temperature of the emitter. But there is also a dependence on emissivity which is governed by the material properties of the emitter like the reflectivity and such. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_thermometer) page for Infrared Thermometer:

> Most surfaces have high emissivity (over 0.9 for most biological surfaces)[citation needed], and most IR thermometers rely on this simplifying assumption; however, reflective surfaces have lower emissivity than non-reflective surfaces. Some sensors have an adjustable emissivity setting, which can be set to measure the temperature of reflective and non-reflective surfaces. A non-adjustable thermometer may be used to measure the temperature of a reflective surface by applying a non-reflective paint or tape, with some loss of accuracy.

So maybe you can modify the emissivity to the right value and see if you get the right temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the right pointer...!! Actually changing the emissivity settings in the IR gun didnt change the measured value... However, painting a black dot with marker pen did bring the value closer to the boiling water value...!! So, apparently, it was indeed an emissivity issue...!!

Answer (score 0):

When the surface is reflecting (like the metal) you are actually measuering then temperature of what can be seen in the reflection, not the reflecting body.